# Python (psycopg2) - Insert NULL (None) within a tuple

Tags: python, postgresql, null, tuples, nonetype

I'm kindly asking for help...

I'am trying to INSERT row into Postgres with values specified in a tuple. It works until one of the values is equal to None (Which I'd like to store as NULL)

This version of curr.execute works:

```
dev_id = '6d89cc68-1b1a-11e8-a339-525400005c6c'
ifid = 1
ifname_id = 1
ifmac = 'nomacpaired'
flag = None
time = ts()

db.cursor.execute("""INSERT into device_ifce (dev_id, ifid, ifname_id, ifmac, flags, updated, created ) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""", (dev_id, ifid, ifname_id, ifmac, flag, time, time))
```

But it is not really handy for me, and I'd like to do it like this:

```
values = (dev_id, ifid, ifname_id, ifmac, flag, time, time)
db.cursor.execute("""INSERT into device_ifce VALUES {}""".format(values))
```

...and I get error:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "none" does not exist
LINE 1: ...b1a-11e8-a339-525400005c6c', 1, 1, 'nomacpaired', None, '201...
```

The other values work fine, but None. If I replace "flag = None" to str (flag = 'foo'), it works.

So my question is: Is it possible to have one of the values in tuple as None or am I doing something wrong ?

Thank you for answers,
Daniel

Comment: How about this - replace `flag,` with `"NULL" if flag is None else flag,`

Comment: It won't work I guess. If you define flag='NULL' the database stores 'NULL' as string, not as empty (non) value. The point is that Python None = Postgres NULL. But I am not able to have None as one of the value in the tuple.

Comment: Handy or not, the working version is **the safe way** of passing values to SQL queries, while your attempts at formatting the values inline are prone to problems and SQL injection.